# Runtime Callable Wrapper Class Not Registered

Tags: c#, dll, vb6, rcw

I have a dll called srxCOM.dll for titan-FTP, this dll was made for VB6. I want to use the dll in Visual Studio .NET, So I created a run-time callable wrapper using tblimp and called it srxCOMnet.dll. I've added the dll as a reference in my VS project and can access functions within it. Upon building the project I get this error,

ERROR: CLSID {A82C6CF0-7B42-4ABD-AECB-987E298A41AF} failed due to the following error: 80040154 Class not registered (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80040154 (REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG)).

After some research I have tried:

- registering srxCOM.dll which was successfull.
- registering the RCW srxCOMnet.dll which failed.
- Changing build options from Any CPU to x86.

I don't want to write my application in VB6, is there anything else I can try?

Comment: If you inspect the original COM DLL to view its typelib info (say by using OLEView) does the CLSID A82C6... mentioned in the question match any of the IDs? That might narrow down the issue

Comment: When you registered srxCOM.dl, did you use the /codebase option or register it in the GAC?  I prefer the former for configurations such as you are describing.

Comment: C# can call VB6 dlls direct.  In VB.Net it is `imports System.Runtime.InteropServices` to turn on COM support. But it has to compile to 32 bit or get dllhost.exe to host the COM dll which means you access it out of process and you can compile to 64 bit but it will be slower.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using a different dll supplied by titanFTP.

I found this codeproject.com:

Primary interop assemblies can reference only other primary interop assemblies. If your assembly references types from a third-party COM type library, you must obtain a primary interop assembly from the publisher before you can generate your primary interop assembly. If you are the publisher, you must generate a primary interop assembly for the dependent type library before generating the referencing primary interop assembly.

See this link below

[codeproject Using-Unmanaged-VB-Code-in-NET](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/154144/Using-Unmanaged-VB-Code-in-NET)